# Why doesn't CheckBoxMenuItem generate action events?

Tags: java, awt, action, popupmenu

I'm building an AWT PopupMenu containing several MenuItems. These items have ActionListeners that trigger commands when clicked on.

ActionListeners added to plain MenuItems work properly, but CheckboxMenuItems don't seem to generate any action events. Nothing happens at all. This is unexpected, considering they directly inherit the `addActionListener()` method from MenuItem.

This problem seems to be known, and quite old: http://www.coderanch.com/t/197173/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/ActionListener-CheckboxMenuItem

Why is this happening, and how could I make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't know why `addActionListener()` does nothing, but it turns out that`addItemListener()` did the trick.

That will be enough for me.

Comment: "When a check box menu item is selected, AWT sends an item event to the item. Since the event is an instance of ItemEvent[...]" - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/CheckboxMenuItem.html